# UI element distances by code depend on the screen size. Workaround?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have problems positioning and moving elements on Unity canvas by code, because the absolute distances tend to depend on the screen size. So, if I want to make certain point on the screen accessible by code (i.e. move certain UI element to that point), I use this workaround:

1) In the editor, I create a small "auxiliary" panel (in the same hierarchy level as the element I want to move), place it in the desired position and disable its Image.

2) Then, to move the element, I use this code (roughly):

```
Vector2 pos = auxiliaryPanel.GetComponent<RectTrasform>().localPosition;
element.GetComponent<RectTrasform>().localPosition = pos;
```

The problem is when I want to cover multiple positions on the screen. Then I simply need multiple auxiliary panels :)
Any ideas for a cleaner or a more comfortable solution?

Comment: Note: This is a UNITY - related question! (I probably made a search-engine mistake by adding "user-interface" tag...)

Comment: OK, stackoverflow team doesn't allow me to delete the question and repost it with the correct tags... So be it. I am activating the question again, answers and comments are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a position relative to the bounds of the element's parent.

I wrote the following MonoBehaviour to exemplify the idea:

```cs
using UnityEngine;

// component that positions the element at relative position within it's parent
public class PositionElement : MonoBehaviour
{
    // relative position. (0, 0) is the parents lower-left corner and (1, 1) is parents top-right
    public Vector2 relativePosition = new Vector2(0.5f, 0.5f);

    private void Update()
    {
        // get the parent's RectTransform
        RectTransform parent = (RectTransform)transform.parent;

        // position the element relative the parents lower left corner
        transform.localPosition = Vector2.Scale(parent.rect.size, relativePosition - parent.pivot);
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: You are right. I'd rather use `transform.localPosition = Vector2.Scale(parent.rect.size, relativePosition);`, and now I have 4 clearly defined points of reference (the parent corners) plus not-so-clearly defined space between them.